# Is there clever ruby string method to create text bargraph such as "XXX-------" if passed 3 and 10?

Tags: ruby, string

I need to write a method to create a simple text bar chart given a value and maxvalue. So `barchart(4, 10)` would return `"XXXX------"`.

It's obviously trivially simple to just code that, but I'm trying to learn more about ruby string methods.

The nest I could come up with was: if you want, for example, 4/10 (i.e. an output of `"XXXX------"`),

```
graph = "".ljust(4, 'X').ljust(10, '-')
```

But that seems goofy, I suspect there's a more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way using [string multiplication](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2A):

```
 passed = 4
 d = 'X' * passed + '-' * (10 - passed)
```

Whether or not this is "less goofy" is undecided.

Comment: I didnt know about the "X" * 4 to create "XXXX" - nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well you can just use string multiplication and addition.

```
d = "X" * 4 + "-" * 10
```

Comment: Please explain ? why will it add more - than specified by the multiplier ?

Comment: Oh, now I get it...I just misunderstood that part, he wants 10 chars maximum. So it's still the same idea, just a substraction...